# Issue to get current system datetime dynamically using windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

Issue:
I am changing current system format from `MM/dd/yyyy` to `MM/dd/yy`

In console application i am using the code as follows

```
DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

output is :`18/08/13`

In windows service the same code i am using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

but output was :`18/08/2013`

I checked by reinstalling service also.But no use.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just force the format with `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy")` or by using a specific `CultureInfo`? You would evade inconsistencies.

Comment: If i restrict format to DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy") means its working.But what i want is i want to display the date in system settings format.I used the code to get current system date format as follows DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern());.The above code also not giving correct output

Answer (score 1):

The answer to [this forum question](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.480326.2) says:

> If your Windows Service is running under the SYSTEM account or other
>   account without a profile it will use the settings defined under the
>   **HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/Control Panel/International** registry key.
>
> You can change these values from **Control Panel / Regional and
>   Language Options / Advanced** by checking the check box **Apply all
>   settings to the current user account and to the default user profile**.

Also, read more about the issue on this similar question: [Why is my CurrentCulture en-GB and my CurrentUICulture en-US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732468/why-is-my-currentculture-en-gb-and-my-currentuiculture-en-us).